# Flutter App is not running in the iOS platform

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have upgraded my flutter after that I got this issue. it is running in the android perfectly but in iOS its not working and getting this error. Here I have shared the output. please help me out I have spent so many hours to resolve this but couldn't find any solution.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            4.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/alumniassociation02/Documents/my_app/ios/Runner/Info.plist:0: error: reading data: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Here is Xcode project structure and Android studio project structure--

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzcWI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50RAv.png

Updated Xcode project directory image
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lya26.jpg

Comment: please open Xcode project (iOS app project) and check whether `Info.plist` is there or not.

Comment: Most probably the issue is `Info.plist` file is missing. OR may be the path of the `Info.plist` file has been changed.

Comment: how do i know the file path has changed? cause it is showing the same in the xcode. info.plist fiile is missing

Comment: you can go to Build Settings from Xcode project. and search for info.plist. You will see the path for that file. If the path is not set then you need to set it

Comment: hey, @Mahendra please let me know that where I am missing the path of info.plist I have updated my question and listed some screenshot of the project structure in xcode.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hi @Mahendra it didn't solve yet please look at my updated Xcode project directory mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your project structure of the Xcode project, I can say that Info.plist file path is not correctly set in your project.

Please see blow image of my project (see the location of **Info.plist**)

[image]

It is your project structure.

[image]

Please see the blow image for the **Info.plist** file path.

[image]

Hope this will help you:)

Comment: have you checked the Info.plist file path in Xcode project?

Comment: please check above image - how to see info.plist file path